# IntelliJ - Cannot build gradle project in software, but works in terminal using gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, ssl, intellij-idea, keystore, intellij-14

When I build my gradle project in IntelliJ I get the error "password verification failed" and "org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

[image: IntelliJ error message]

However, if I run ./gradlew build from terminal (even in the IntelliJ terminal) I get a successful build. I am assuming there are some intelliJ settings I have entered incorrectly somewhere? I have attached my settings as they currently are for gradle:

[image: Gradle IntelliJ settings]

I am on a macbook.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the answers with a similar error message to see if there's any solution? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Keystore+was+tampered+with%2C+or+password+was+incorrect

Comment: Is it an Android project? Do you use the same JDK for Gradle in IDE as you use from terminal?

Comment: Yes I have looked at these, my keystore is fine to open via terminal and have no issues there - It is only in intelliJ. Same JDK for both yes.